# How to preprocess file before Feeds upload

Tags: feeds

I am using Feeds 7.x-2.0-beta1 .  I am getting the data in a format that I need to change before inputting, since they are adding one item per row when some data has multiple values in one field . I want to modify the file to put all of those values in one field and one row before continuing with the feeds parser.
Where can I put the php code to do this? what hooks are available? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Feeds project page doesn't advertise it, but there is an API. If you look at [**feeds.api.php**](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21feeds.api.php/7) you can view all the hooks it makes available. A few of them take action before a feed item is processed or saved.

Comment: This hook shows you the result right after parsing before processing     function mymodulename_feeds_after_parse( $source, $result){
  echo " on line 228 , the result is <pre>";
  dprint_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
  
}